# Excel xmatch min AND max values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The Excel formula XMATCH has a third argument that returns a value if the value being tested is EITHER greater OR less than the list of values.  I need it to return a numeric value in all cases - Less than the minimum (7 in the example below), within the values (1-7 in the example) or greater than the maximum (1 in the example) .

Example
[image]

I'm trying to avoid an IF that tests for #N/A. The real use of the XMATCH in this case is inside an INDEX function and it gets hard to read / debug with extra IF logic.
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: All the numbers are greater than -1564% which means there is no number that is less than or equal to that, hence the error.  Just do: `IFERROR(XMATCH(....),7)` for the less than the minimum or `IFERROR(XMATCH(...),1)` for the larger than max.  or since those numbers will really not mean anything just make them impossible large and impossibly small.

Comment: @ScottCraner - if you were to apply this logic to a long list of arrays / table instead of just two rows - then how do you see that working? my proposal below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot see a way to do it without *any* type of error checking - but this is fairly parsimonious:

```
=MAX(IFERROR(XMATCH(J1,C1:I1,{-1,1}),""))
```

[image: Sample]

Caveat: if there are two valid solutions (e.g. as for lookup -50% in second row), you can alternate between which value you want by changing max to min, or return both by simply removing the outer function altogether, depends upon your circumstances...

---

---

**Aside**

*Note, whilst this part is outside the scope of your core Q, I thought it worth mentioning that you may want to explore other Office 360 functions to assist with lengthy / compound functions - as you've alluded.  An excellent e.g. is 'let' which would allow you to define this function upfront, and then refer back to it as many times as you need to within a compound function. The obvious advantage is that you only need to check it once; further, if used apprporiately, it can compresses/shorten the length of the compound function considerably.*

*Here's an example the uses the above function to lookup the result in one index, and then a second index if not found in the first..*

[image: Bonus example / sample e.g.]

```
=LET(x_,MAX(IFERROR(XMATCH(J1,C1:I1,{-1,1}),"")),IFERROR(INDEX(N$2#,MATCH(x_,M$2#,0)),INDEX(Q$2#,MATCH(x_,P$2#,0))))
```

Comment: Thanks for confirmation that it needs error checking.  

Also kudos for using parsimonious in a SO answer!  Although I think of my formulas as frugal.  ;-)

Comment: np - I did try to find a way - but trying to avoid errors where these are bound to arise is futile, nevermind fugile ! :) :) lol Br, J

Comment: (PS - lol, do you mean to give me kudos for eloquent speech haha!) np - have good evening pal#

Answer (score 2):

What about `XLOOKUP()` which has the ability to handle errors:

[image]

```
=XLOOKUP(J1,C1:I1,SEQUENCE(,7),7,-1)
```

Comment: hey @JvdV - my fellow SA man! Howsit goin' bra? Keep it shweet.  ciao

Comment: PS - RE your xlookup - might as well use hlookup (given cell alignment in Q) with final parm = 0/False, yeah? the only thing I'll give v/hlookup over index is that 'fuzzyfind' facility / feature.  sometimes comes in handy despite the silly 'only to right/down' lookup requirement lol :)